# How to connect the 3.3v pin of arduino mega to multiple sensors

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I am connecting 3 accelerometers to an arduino mega. I have everything except how to connect them to the 3.3v pin. I know that I can just connect the 3 of them to the same ground pin but I have been told I can't do the same with 3.3v pin. Can anyone tell me what is the best way to power them from the arduino mega?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect all of them as long as the total current draw is not over 50mA as described [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega). If you need more than 50mA, you need to create your own 3.3v supply or use something like a breadboard power supply for instance (keep in mind to make a shared ground line).

Comment: Yes sorry, that's what I meant by connecting the 3 ground wires to the same ground pin. Can I do the same with the 3.3v pin then? Is that what you're saying? Just use a shared 3.3v line?

Comment: yes, take a look at the datasheet of your sensors. There should be a Max current field in the specs. If the **sum** of total max current in each sensor is less than 50mA you can use the 3.3v of arduino mega.